# I can run playbook on user but not on crontab

Tags: cron, logs, ansible

Hey everybody as i said in title i can run my playbooks in ansible but not in crontab, doesn't reach the machine, i entered correctly the ssh key, and become a ssh agent, i'll show you my code and my logs.

```
#*/1 * * * * ansible-playbook /home/user/updateapt.yml  >> /home/user/ansiblelogs/ansible_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S).log 2>&1
```

logs:

```
load

PLAY [actualizar server APT] ***************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [ansible@x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ansible@x.x.x.x        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

i'll try multiples codes and unixstackexchange treats but doesn't work. the user is in sudoers tab.

Only one Worked before but as u can see is a very harmful code, and obviously u shouldn't insert this code in crontab it's very insecure, ill show u.

```
*/1 * * * * echo "user-password" | sudo -S ansible-playbook /home/user/updateapt.yml  >> /home/user/ansiblelogs/ansible_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S).log 2>&1
```

Comment: `Host key verification failed` <--- explicitly says what the problem is.

Comment: Either accept the host key as that user, or set `host_key_checking = False` in `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: yes i solved this issue, i forgot to eval ssh, but as same as yesterday i can't log, now this is the message.  to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions or updates to the situation in comments. Rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738385/edit) your question so it stays up-to-date with your situation, and the relevant data is readily available.

Comment: When you run ansible-playbook from cron you don't have the same environment as when you run it from the command line. You have neither ssh-agent to provide the ssh private key's password nor gpg-agent to provide gpg private key's password. There might be environment variables missing in cron. See [Run Ansible playbooks in cron](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example1-cron.html#example-1-run-ansible-playbooks-in-cron).